How do you share environment variables for multiple stages with your team in a local development environment?
Our team is working on a project with multiple stages (e.g., development, staging, production), each requiring different environment variables. We often need to ensure that everyone on the team uses the correct and updated environment variables for local development.
Currently, we manage this by sharing the variables through a shared Google Sheet, but I feel there might be a better or more efficient way to handle this.
How do you and your team share and manage environment variables for local environments across multiple stages? Are there any tools or best practices you recommend to improve this process?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

We were maintaining Makefile with available targets (i.e. for building docker image, running tests, spinning up local deployment). Next to Makefile we had a folder called .makerc where we stored different values for variables used in Makefile, each file in .makerc was setting up variables for given environment.

Please add your tech stack, all build tools and stacks have different best practices or tooling.
